# Enderton's set theory book. Confused with hierarchy of sets.

Tags: set-theory

Sorry for much text, but i'm trying to avoid ambiguity. In some chapter of his **Elements of set theory** book, Professor Enderton is explaining a *set as part of a hierarchy*. The beginning of a chapter, that l fully understand:

> First we gather together all things that are not sets themselves but that we want to have as members of a set. Lets call them *atoms*. Let *A* be the set of all atoms.
>
> We now proceed to build up a hierarchy:
>
> $\;\;\;\;\;\;\;V_0 \subseteq V_1 \subseteq V_2 \subseteq\;...$
>
> At the bottom level we take $A=V_0$. The next level will contain all sets of atoms:
>
> $\;\;\;\;\;\;\;V_1=V_0\cup \wp(V_0)$
>
> The third level contains everything that is in lower level plus all sets of things from lower levels:
>
> $\;\;\;\;\;\;\;V_2=V_1\cup \wp(V_1)$
>
> And in general:
>
> $\;\;\;\;\;\;\;V_{n+1}=V_n\cup \wp(V_n)$
>
> Thus we obtain successively $V_0$, $V_1$, $V_2$ ...

**And next** comes the part, I don't understand why even worth mentioned:

> But even this infinite hierarchy doesn't include enough sets...

**1)** Why $V_{n+1}$ set doesn't include enough sets? It includes $V_n$ set, that itself includes $V_{n-1}$ set etc., right? Or does author implies, that $V_{n+1}$ set is not a set inevitably super high in a hierarchy - that how i understand it - but random set vice versa?

> ... For example $\varnothing \in V_1$,{$\varnothing$} $\in V_2$,{{$\varnothing$}} $\in V_3$ etc., but we do not yet have the infinite set
>
> $\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;${$\varnothing, ${$\varnothing$}, {{$\varnothing$}}...}

**2)** Also not clear for me.

$\varnothing \in \wp (V_0)$ because $\varnothing$ is a subset of every set, thus $\varnothing \in V_1$, because $V_1=V_0 \cup \wp (V_0)$

$\wp (V_1)$ is a set of all subsets in $V_1$ and {$\varnothing$} is a subset of $V_1$ with single element (that is an empty element), so {$\varnothing$} $\in \wp(V_1)$. Also $\varnothing \in \wp (V_1)$ because $\varnothing$ is a subset of every set. Thus $V_2$, as a union of $V_1$ and $\wp(V_1)$  in its elements has both $\varnothing$ and {$\varnothing$}.

This way we can continue infinitely, i mean for every other higher level of hierarchy there will be one more "empty element with one more pair of braces" and all previous levels' empty element sets. So, **why Professor Enderton wrote:**

> ...but we do not yet have the infinite set {$\varnothing, ${$\varnothing$}, {{$\varnothing$}}...}

Is it again, the deal with $V_n$ being not an infinitely high in hierarchy set, but just some random one? If it so, then i got it, no questions, solved. If it is not the case, also the next (that is last) one comes. The text continues the *"...but we do not..."* line from backquote:

> ...To remedy this lack, we take the infinite union:
>
> $\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;V_{\omega}=V_0\;\cup\;V_1\;\cup\;...$ ,
>
> And then let $V_{\omega+1}=V_{\omega}\cup \wp(V_{\omega})$, and we continue. In general for any $\alpha$,
>
> $\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;V_{\alpha+1}=V_{\alpha}\cup \wp(V_{\alpha})$ ,
>
> and this goes on "forever".

**3)**$V_{\omega}=V_0\;\cup\;V_1\;\cup\;...$ 


But $\;V_1=V_0\;\cup\; \wp(V_0) $ and, if i understand unions properly, $V_0\;\cup\;V_0\; \cup \wp(V_0)=V_0\; \cup \; \wp()V_0$.  So what the reason to insert the union of all hierarchy levels, if the infinitely high level set will already have all previous set's elements? Thus, i again do not understand, why author could not stop on $V_{n+1}$ set.

Again, sorry for so much text. Just trying to be clear. Thank you.

Comment: Think about this: if we stopped at $V_{n+1}$, then we would not contain things in $V_{n+2}$ which we would like to have. This is why we need to "keep going" and union $V_n$ for all natural numbers $n$. (That is, we need a $V_{\alpha}$ that is "infinitely high in the hierarchy".)

Comment: Why *Sir* Enderton? That's not a title he ever received or used. The appropriate one would be Professor.

Comment: Enderton claims that, when we produce $V_n$ for all natural numbers $n$, none of these sets $V_n$ contains the infinite set $S=\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\},\{\{\varnothing\}\},\dots\}$. You seem to think that this is wrong, that one of the sets $V_n$ contains $S$. Can you indicate which $V_n$ this would be, i.e., for which natural number $n$ do we have $S\in V_n$? In fact, $S$ is not in any of these $V_n$'s, nor is it even an element of $V_\omega$. It is, however, a subset of $V_\omega$ and therefore an element of $V_{\omega+1}$.

Comment: Another way to say it is:  when we write $V_n$ we are referring to an unspecified, generic, *but individual* set, not to the collection of all of the sets together.

Comment: (1). Enderson inserts an axiom: That there exists a set of all the atoms. We can build an equally consistent theory with the negation of that....(2).  The motivation  for ever-higher hierarchic levels is to have a sufficiently rich universe that not only has infinite sets, but  has some other"intuitively desirable" properties,such as the existence of power-sets.  We could stop at $\{V_n:n\in \omega\}$ but then we are limited to Peano Arithmetic.

Comment: Thank you all! Sorry about "sir",  thought it is a usual honorific term (like "mr.") in anglophone countries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you might be confusing the notion of *infinite* with *arbitrarily large*. After having built $V_0\subset V_1\subset V_2\subset\cdots$ then we *do* have, as you mention,

$$ \{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\},\{\{\emptyset\}\},\dots,\{\cdots\{\emptyset\}\cdots\}\}\in V_{n+1}$$,

where the last $\emptyset$ has $n$ brackets, for every finite $n$. But just because we have these arbitrarily large finite pieces, it doesn't mean that we get the infinite set

$$ \{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\},\{\{\emptyset\}\},\dots\}$$

in one of the $V_n$'s, since these only contain finite sets, as we've only applied the power set finitely many times at that stage. To continue the hierarchy after all the finite stages we need to get a set containing all of the $V_n$'s. This set can't be one of the $V_n$'s, as the $V_n$'s only have finitely many elements and the set that we're looking for has to contain $\emptyset$, $\{\emptyset\}$, $\{\{\emptyset\}\}$ and so on. The least set containing all the $V_n$'s is the union of them all, $\bigcup_{n<\omega}V_n$, which we then call $V_\omega$, and continue taking power sets. Since

$$ \emptyset,\{\emptyset\},\{\{\emptyset\}\},\dots\in V_\omega$$

we then get that

$$ \{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\},\{\{\emptyset\}\},\dots\}\in V_{\omega+1}$$,

as it's a subset of $V_\omega$.

Comment: Thank you! Now i've got it.